# How can I re-initialize gapi on page refresh using Google oAuth in React?

Tags: reactjs, oauth, gis, google-signin, google-api-js-client

I've been working on integrating Google Sign-In for my application and have run into an intriguing problem. While the sign-in process is seamless and works as expected, I've noticed that upon refreshing the page, I seem to lose my connection to gapi. I still retain both the userDetails and the accessToken.

I use gapi later on in my application to fetch calendar events, and it's crucial that this connection remains intact even after a page refresh. Everything seemed to be functioning fine until I encountered this hiccup. My primary function for the Google Sign-In process seems to be the root of the problem.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { gapi } from "gapi-script";
import axios from "axios";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const google = window.google;

export const useGoogleSignIn = () => {

  const [googleAccessToken, setGoogleAccessToken] = useState();
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState();
  const { hotCredintials } = useSelector((state) => state.hotCredintials);
      const apiKey = "";
      const clientID =  "";
        const refreshToken =  ""
        const   clientSecret = ""

  useEffect(() => {
    // fetchData(apiRoutes.hotCredentials).then((res) => setCredentialKeys(res));
    const accessTkn = localStorage.getItem("googleAccessToken");
    setGoogleAccessToken((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      access_token: JSON.parse(accessTkn),
    }));
  }, []);

  const onGoogleSignIn = () => {
const timestampInMilliseconds = new Date().getTime();

/* client google */
const client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
  client_id: hotCredintials.find(({ credentialId }) => credentialId === "3")
    ?.credentialValue,
  scope: SCOPES,
  callback: (tokenResponse) => {
    if (tokenResponse && tokenResponse?.access_token) {
      setGoogleAccessToken(tokenResponse);
      localStorage.setItem(
        "googleAccessToken",
        JSON.stringify(tokenResponse.access_token)
      );
      localStorage.setItem(
        "googleAccessTokenExpire",
        JSON.stringify(timestampInMilliseconds)
      );
      gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    }
  },
});

client.requestAccessToken();
  };

  const onGoogleSignOut = () => {
    google.accounts.id.disableAutoSelect();
    // google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(googleAccessToken.access_token);
    setGoogleAccessToken("");
    setUserDetails("");
    localStorage.removeItem("googleAccessToken");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // refresh access token before it expires
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      const expireTime = Number(
        localStorage.getItem("googleAccessTokenExpire")
      );
      const timeLimit = expireTime + 3580 * 1000; // Convert 3580 seconds to milliseconds and add to expireTime
      const timeNow = new Date().getTime();
  if (googleAccessToken.access_token && timeNow > timeLimit) {
    axios
      .post(`https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`, {
        client_id: clientID,
        client_secret: clientSecret,
        grant_type: "refresh_token",
        refresh_token:
        refreshToken
          

      })
      .then((res) => {
        setGoogleAccessToken((prev) => {
          return {
            ...prev,
            access_token: res.data.access_token,
            expires_in: res.data.expires_in,
            token_type: res.data.token_type,
            scope: res.data.scope,
          };
        });
        localStorage.setItem(
          "googleAccessToken",
          JSON.stringify(res.data.access_token)
        );
        localStorage.setItem(
          "googleAccessTokenExpire",
          JSON.stringify(newTimestampInMilliseconds)
        );
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
}, 10000); // Refresh every 10 seconds

// Cleanup function to clear the interval
return () => clearInterval(intervalId);


 }, [googleAccessToken]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (googleAccessToken?.access_token)
      fetch(
        `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=${googleAccessToken.access_token}`
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((content) => {
          setUserDetails(content);
          gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
  }, [googleAccessToken]);

  return {
    onGoogleSignIn,
    onGoogleSignOut,
    userDetails,
  };
};
```

Comment: Could you find any written proof from Google that we need to re-initialize gapi upon page refreshing? I also encountered the same issue. But if we can get any written information from Google regarding that it will be much worth I think. @aarriiaann

Comment: No I cound not find any Google proof for re-initalize gapi. I discovered myself how to reinitialize otherwise gapi wont work after refresh. @Jack

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by authorizing gapi

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (googleAccessToken?.access_token)
      gapi.auth.authorize(
        {
          client_id: clientID,
          scope: SCOPES,
          immediate: true,
        },
        function (authResult) {
          console.log({ authResult });
          if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
            // gapi.auth.setToken(googleAccessToken);
          } else {
            console.log("Failed to set token:", authResult.error);
          }
        }
      );
  }, [googleAccessToken]);
```